# How does the browser manage it's memory or clean its DOM?

Tags: dom, backbone.js, browser

I am learning Backbone and want to better understand how the browser keeps it DOM clean and how to be efficient overall with my code. From my understanding, we use Backbone as a framework to throw on views onto an element that is usually found in the index.html (most of the time being the body tag). The view we throw in uses up the Browser's memory, and because of this, we want to do something like `$(body).html('')` to erase everything when we switch to another view or no longer need the old view. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the modern browsers have Garbage Collection, you don't have to actually worry (much) about that.

The few cases where the browser doesn't free up memory is because you have a memory leak in your code and references are being kept for your objects, methods, variables, etc.

Google for it, mozilla has some examples to do memory profiling in the browser.